# Orbits and stabilizers of a group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We have the following Group $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ acting on $\mathbb{R²}$ with 
\begin{matrix}
\mathbb{R^{\times}} \times \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \\ 
 (t,(x,y)) \mapsto (tx, \frac{y}{t})
\end{matrix}

How to compute the (i) orbits and (ii) stabilizers ?

(i) I would say that the orbit of such an element $x=(a,b)$ is 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{R}^{\times}.x=\{(ta, \frac{b}{t}) \vert t \in \mathbb{R}^{\times} \}
\end{equation}

or given by the linear function 
\begin{equation}
f(t) = \frac{ta - a}{b - \frac{b}{t}}, \text{ where } t \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{ 0 \}
\end{equation}

(ii) The stabilizer $\mathbb{R}^{\times}_x = \{1\}$ because $(x,y) = (tx, \frac{y}{t})$ only if $t=1$.

This was my approach and i would appreciate some help to work this out.

Comment: how do you get that $f$?

Comment: i just wanted to express $\mathbb{R}^{\times}.x$ as a linear function...

Comment: Why do you believe $\mathbb{R}^\times x$ is linear? Note there is one element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a different stabilizer subgroup.

Comment: oh right, $\frac{b}{t}$ isn't linear for increasing or decreasing $t$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simpler hint for (i)**:

If $x\ne 0$ and $y\ne 0$ observe that, for any $t\ne 0$, we have
$$tx\cdot\frac yt=xy,$$
so the orbit of $(x,y)$ is a well-known curve.

Next, consider separately the cases $x=0,\:y\ne 0$, $x\ne 0, \: y=0$, $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: thx for answering. In the first case the orbit of $(x,y)$ is a hyperbola $y = \frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: Yes, clearly almost all the orbits are  a pencil of hyperbolas, and two of the limiting cases are their common asymptotes. Better define the equations of the hyperbolas/orbits as $xy=x_0y_0$ for the orbit of $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: got it, many thanks!